# Partitioning for Ubuntu 32 and 64 on one drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I need to have portable drive with 32 and 64 bit Ubuntu. Which partitions should be created?

Answer (score 1):

This will share a home partition:

1. Boot one of the live CDs. On the partitioning stage, select [Something Else].
2. Shrink your existing partition by at least 200GB if you want to keep it, or delete all partitions if you don't want to keep it.
3. Add a new partition of about 40 GB to act as your home partition. This will be shared between the installations. Set it to be formatted as Ext4, and set the mount point to `/home`.
4. Create a swap partition or a few GB, and set the Use As to "Linux Swap".
5. Create another partition taking approximately half the remaining space. Set it to be formatted, as Ext4. Set the mount point to `/`.
6. Finish the installation. Then, boot the other CD.
7. Go to advanced partitioning.
8. Click Edit on the home partition you created in step 3. Set the mount point to `/home`. ***Do not*** change the file system or check the Format box.
9. Create a new partition to be the swap for this installation(using the method in step 4).
10. Create a new root partition as in Step 5. Fill the space on the drive.

Finish the installation. Any accounts with the same username will be shared as long as they have the same UID(Settings->Users->Advanced settings).

To install without sharing a home partition, just skip steps 3 and 8. Leave the rest as is, using all space on the drive.